# Any way with Entity Framework Code First to get nice picture of class structure?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm use to having tools that give me a nice detailed view of my data relationships. Anyway of doing this with code-first? Below is the kind of diagram I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Entity Framework Power Tools (currently in CTP) allows you to visualize the model generated by Code First using the Entity Designer. Find the download here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d.

Comment: Even 3 years later, the tool is inadequate for anything more than the most basic of data models. It fails to parse even Microsoft driven libraries like ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 7):

How about the [Visual Studio Class Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288743%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - present since VS 2005.

[image]

Basically do a `Add New Item -> Code -> Class Diagram` from your solution explorer and drag those classes onto the design surface that you want to have visualized.

Comment: Strangely, I just see a blank space where the image should be (on mobile). Not sure if something is wrong with the linked image.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: what if you follow the link I posted in my answer? The image is linked from that article (on MSDN)

Comment: I think I see it there (no images appear to be missing there)